# How do I stop Outlook.com from following links in email?

Tags: php, outlook, web-crawler

As part of account registration I send an email to the new user with a one-time verification link which confirms the existence of their email address and automatically signs them in. However, I've noticed that the verification script is run when the email is opened -- before the link itself is clicked. My assumption is that my email client (Outlook.com in this case) has some sort of crawler which is following the link in the email when it is opened.

Assuming I'm correct (and if I'm not, please correct me), and leaving aside what is potentially a severe breach of privacy (as that's off-topic here) is there anything I can do to stop this from happening?

To confirm that it is indeed Outlook.com I checked the User Agent, which is `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0` (I'm using Chrome on a Mac) and the remote address, which is `132.245.26.156` (owned by Microsoft).

Comment: mail clients by default don't fetch remote resources anymore. unless that particular outlook has some funky/bad security settings, or the recipient's explicitly allowed outlook to trust that particular sender.

Comment: It was Outlook.com. I did mark the sender as trusted. Is that the explanation?

Comment: untrust the sender and try again...

Comment: Will do when I'm back at work tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: have you tried to give the link attribute `rel="nofollow"`?

Comment: Also, if Outlook is indeed following that link by itself, you might be able to detect that via UserAgent.

Comment: `rel="nofollow"` doesn't work and removing them as a trusted sender doesn't work. It doesn't follow the link when in the junk folder but when moved to the inbox and unblocked (but not marked as trusted) the link is followed.

Comment: Don't chrome and other browsers prefetch links in the page you're viewing to speed up browsing?  Are you sure that setting is off?

Comment: The remote address points to Microsoft and the user agent to a Windows machine, though.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and have been testing with hotmail.com & outlook.com email addresses. I guess the problem applies to all Microsoft email addresses (so also with msn & live). Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is related to the "Link Preview" feature of Outlook.com.

Outlook will detect a valid link and display a preview in the email. 
Somehow it will be considered a "click" from the user.

Ideally, users would need to have the feature disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue, user is getting verified as soon as he opens the email without clicking the link. I think the only solution is to have a user perform an action once at the verify page like click a Verify Button or something, we could specifically do this for just Microsoft emails.